# How do you work a tryCatch with numbers and Letters

Tags: format

I am supposed to ADD a TRY-CATCH to make sure the user inputs a numeric value and not a letter value. It works fine when you enter a letter and reads "there was an error, please enter digits" but then the program stops and says there was an error : [image]

Here is my code

Dim intPoints As Integer

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    txtPoints.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    End
End Sub
Private Sub btnReward_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReward.Click

    Try
        intPoints = txtPoints.Text

        intPoints = Convert.ToInt32(txtPoints.Text)

    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error, please enter digits")

    End Try

    'intPoints = Convert.ToInt32(txtPoints.Text)



    If txtPoints.Text <= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You cannot have less than 0")
    End If
    If txtPoints.Text = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Keep Trying")
    End If
    If txtPoints.Text = 2 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Keep Trying")
    End If
    If txtPoints.Text = 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Keep Trying")
    End If
    If txtPoints.Text = 4 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Keep Trying")
    End If

    If txtPoints.Text = 5 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You're Gettomg close, just a few more!")
    End If
    If txtPoints.Text = 6 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You're Gettomg close, just a few more!")
    End If
    If txtPoints.Text = 7 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You're Gettomg close, just a few more!")
    End If
    If txtPoints.Text = 8 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You're Gettomg close, just a few more!")
    End If
    If txtPoints.Text = 9 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Almost, just one more!")
    End If
    If txtPoints.Text = 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Awesome! You earned a reward!")
    End If
    If txtPoints.Text >= 11 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You cannot have more than 10 points")
    End If


End Sub
' A computer uses
```

End Class